# How simple is it to solve this Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How to solve this Differential Equation?
How simple is it to solve this Differential Equation?
Any guidelines? Any hint? How to approach the solution?
Have anybody seen things like it before? ...

$$
\frac{d^2F}{dg^2} \cdot \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} \cdot \frac{\partial G}{\partial v}
+\frac{dF}{dg} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial u \partial v}
-\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial p \partial q} \cdot \frac{dP}{du} \cdot \frac{dQ}{dv} = 0.
$$

It is required to find $F(g)$

$F$ is a function of $g$: $$F(g) = f$$
$g$ depends on $u$ and $v$: $$g = G(u,v)$$
$H$ is a function of $p$ and $q$: $$H(p,q) = h$$
$p$ depends on $u$: $$p = P(u)$$
$q$ depends on $v$: $$q = Q(v)$$